# How to design : Defining a set of strategy(s) for each business rule

Tags: c#, rule-engine

I am working on a windows service to process a batch of records.
In this I have a set of processors to process my records based on a set of conditions.
So I have a Engine class which looks something like this :

```
public interface IProcessor
{         
    ICollection<OutputEntity> Process(ICollection<InputEntity>> entities);
    string SomeField{get;set;}
}


public class Engine
{
    public Engine(IEnumerable<IProcessor> processors)
    {
        //asign the processors to local variable
    }

    public void ProcessRecords(IService service)
    {
        // getRecords code etc.
        foreach(var processor in processors)
        {
            processor.Process(typeRecords.Where(typeRecord => typeRecord.SomeField == processor.SomeField));
        }
    }
}
```

This is based on another question I has posted a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029254/how-to-implement-usage-of-multiple-strategies-at-runtime).
Now my requirement is that I have some more conditions coming into play based on things like Current Day , some attributes on a set of entities etc.
And on every condition I need to use a combination of processors in a certain sequence.
For instance :

```
if (( DateTime.Now.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) && (inputEntityInstance.Property1 == "X" ))
            {
                Processor1.Process(inputEntityInstance);
                Processor2.Process(inputEntityInstance);
                Processor3.Process(inputEntityInstance):
            }

            if (( IsLastDayOfMonth() && (inputEntityInstance.Property2 == "Y" ))
            {
                Processor1.Process(inputEntityInstance);
                Processor4.Process(inputEntityInstance);
                Processor6.Process(inputEntityInstance):
            }
```

\

However the situation I have now is that I have around 10 types of processors.
For any give condition , about 3 or 4 are applicable.

Whats the best way to implement this .. I was looking at implementing some
kind of a rule engine ..

The idea is that if tomorrow a new condition /rule is to be implemented
I could define it somewhere along with the set of processors and the sequence required ... is this advisable ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the conditions by specification pattern. Run before the related processes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern